# jquery mobile sidebar not expected drag

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, cordova, scroll

I'm working on a phonegap app that has a fixed sidebar behind the page and I found an behavior issue.

The sidebar is hidden, the user can see it with a tap on a menu icon. When the user tap on he icon the page go to the right and it shows the sidebar that is in a minor z-index.

If the user want to close the menu he have to drag the visible part of the page to the left.

My problem was that in the sidebar I have a block that is vertically scrollable. It works fine but the thing is, if I put the .scroll (overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;) class in this element and the user swipe horizontally from right to left over it the sidebar and the page start a drag.

We're using snap.js for the sidebar interaction.

I want to disable this drag. I tried with CSS and preventing horizontal scroll but it doesn't work.

I attach a pic for more visual details.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use iScroll5 for scrolling.
Then hook into the onScrollStart event:

```
myScroll.on('beforeScrollStart', function(event)
    {
        if (isPanelOpen){
            myScroll.disable();
        }
        else{
            myScroll.enable();
        }
    });
```

Or - if you not wanna use iScroll5, you can set a global bool, which indicates, if a panel is open (you've gotta do this anyway).
If a Panel is open (meaning, you're showing the sidebar) set the bool to true in snap.js - this subsequently means, you've gotta tweak snap.js.
Then, on touchmove, check the bool if it is true. Then you know, a panel is open, and you can do a event.stopPropagation on touchmove in order to prevent the event bubbling up to get recognized by snap.js and avoid the panels closes too early.

Comment: Thanks for your answer TorchMan!

Comment: Jake has pretty good comments in his js. You'll find the places, where the panel slide opens and then set the bool to global var. Then hook into touchmove event and check the bool..

Answer (score 0):

Woop! We found it!

The problem was that we're catching the touchmove event for each element with .scroll class and we're stoping the propagation of it.

We had notice that when we tried to start a horizontal scroll all page was moving like a drag so we added this CSS property:

html, body, .ui-mobile .ui-page-active { overflow-x: hidden; }

And...it works fine!

P.S. we don't actually need the horizontal scroll in any element, so, this is fine for us.